# How to remove string within a mixed list and place it back again?

Tags: python, python-3.x

No modules please.

I have a list of lists of numbers and an empty string.

```
new_lst = [['', 0.0, 0.1, 0.2] , ['', '', 0.2 , 0.3], [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]]
```

I used

```
lst = [x for x in lst if x!= '']
```

to remove ''.

I have a bunch of calculations after this, so I needed to remove '' (unless there are other ways to do calculations and ignore all str?). After these calculations, I want to be able to insert the '' back wherever the '' was removed without having to type in the index like so:

```
new_lst[:1].insert(0, '')
```

I need a code that finds wherever the '' was removed and inserts '' back into that index.

```
new_lst = []
for i in range(3):
    lst = ['', 0.0, 0.1, 0.2] , ['', 0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]]

    lst = [x for x in lst if x!= '']

    #do calculations here . for example, for x in lst, add 1.0

    new_lst.append(lst)

new_lst[:1].insert(0, '')
print(new_lst)

#expected output:
new_lst = [['', 1.0, 1.1, 1.2] , ['', '', 1.2, 1.3], [1.1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3]]
```

Comment: Do you need all the values in the list at the same time? Otherwise, I would simply split the list into 2 lists, perform the calculations, and then join them again.

Comment: Is there guaranteed to only be one `''` value in each list? If that's the case, you can use `lst.index('')` to find the _first_ index of an empty string

Comment: @G.Anderson Edited my post. My actual list of lists is long and some of them do have more than one ' '.

Comment: in one of your comments you said that your "calculations" can be a `max`, `min` operation on a sublist. But by doing this lengths of your sublists are going to change, so my question: are empty strings all located at the beginning of a sublist? If no, where do you want to reinsert them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you asked for: removes, calculates and inserts back.
In the following example I add max and min to each value:

```
new_lst = [['', 0.0, 0.1, 0.2] , ['', '', 0.2 , 0.3], [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]]


def foo(subl):
    # get indxes and remove empty strings
    indx = [i for i, x in enumerate(subl) if x == ""]
    subl = list(filter(lambda x: x != "", subl))

    # do calculations here
    M, m = max(subl), min(subl)
    subl = [x + (M+m) for x in subl]

    # empty strings back
    [subl.insert(i, "") for i in indx]
    return subl


new_lst = [foo(subl) for subl in new_lst]
new_lst
```

**Output:**

```
[['', 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4],
 ['', '', 0.7, 0.8],
 [0.5, 0.5, 0.6000000000000001, 0.7]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use list comprehension:

```
def logic_func(x):
    return x+ 1.0

single_lst = ['', 0.0, 0.1, 0.2]
new_single_lst =  [logic_func(x) if x != '' else x for x in single_lst]

print(new_single_lst)
```

This way you apply the logic only to non empty strings.

Comment: You can write ```if x != ''``` as ```if x```. I think it is cleaner.

Comment: It will be a problem with zero values.

Comment: Yeah! Well noticed, @Michal Yanko

Comment: This is better (cleaner, shorter, simpler) than my solution and also works well if multiple quotes are present in one list.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need all the values in the list at once. Then you can:

1. Find the location of the quotes, if present
2. Split the list into two parts (if quotes were present)
3. Perform the calculation (possibly twice)
4. Join the parts and the quotes again

```
lists = [['', 0.0, 0.1, 0.2], ['', 0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.1, 0.1, '', 0.2, 0.3]]

for lst in lists:
    try:
        split_index = lst.index('')

        first_part = lst[:split_index]
        second_part = lst[split_index + 1:]

        # perform calculation

        # join lists again and insert the quotes in the correct place
        new_list = first_part + [''] + second_part

    except ValueError:
        # no need to split and join here, you can just use the complete list

        # perform calculation

        new_list = lst
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fun(a):
    # performing mathematical offeration on east sublist 
    return [i+1 if i!='' else i for i in a]

lst = [['', 0.0, 0.1, 0.2] , ['', 0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]]

new_list = list(map(lambda x: fun(x),lst))

print(new_list)
```

output

```
[['', 1.0, 1.1, 1.2], ['', 1.1, 1.2, 1.3], [1.1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3]]
```